# Enemy level too high in Playthrough 1

Tags: borderlands

I was playing Borderlands and managed to finish most of the game with one of my friends who hosted the game. The only things we didn't do were the DLC arenas and the Crawmerax quest. Our levels were 46 and it was still playthrough 1.

I then asked another one of my friends to join me (I hosted the game) with a high-level character, 69, to tank Crawmerax. That went quite well, I gained 2 levels and then we stopped the game.

Now my problem is, whenever I try to play solo continuing my playthrough 1, all the enemies are scaled to this 2nd friend's level I think; basically, any enemy I see is at level 62.

Is there any way I could revert this back to what it should be? I tried inviting a friend with a lower level to see if it helps but it didn't :(

Edit: playthrough 2 seems to be fine but there's still some stuff I wanted to do in playthrough 1 - like farming MINAC for the silly achievement items.

Comment: Well if you need help with it you better do it fast since they are gonna shut down servers on PS3 and PC...unless your one of those lucky few XBox people

Comment: Yes, I play it on pc/steam. I was hoping there was a way of reverting this situation though.
What date is the server shut-down thing scheduled for anyway?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, perhaps the steam edition will be different though will have to research it.

Comment: Relevant to the server shutting down, perhaps a program like Tunngle will be able to allow players to continue playing the game after the server lock.

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen an issue like this, insofar as you detail. My theory is that the enemies you speak of are only in DLC4 (Claptrap's New Robot Revolution) in correspondence with information from the "[Starting Levels & Triggers](http://forums.gearboxsoftware.com/showthread.php?t=118261)" Gearbox Software Forum thread:

> ## 6. START OF PT1 FOR DLC1 and DLC4
>
> They both start by default at LV10 and keep scaling upon completion of plot missions from the MG PT1. Only DLC4 continues scaling upon completion of certain plot missions from DLC3 PT1. Completing the following plot missions triggers the corresponding starting levels as shown here:
>
> **Starting Level : Trigger**
>   LV10: The default starting level after completing “Skaggs at The Gate” rated for LV2.
>   LV15: “Sledge: The Mine Key” rated for LV10.
>   LV20: “Getting Lucky” rated for LV18.
>   LV25: “Power To The People” rated for LV20.
>   LV30: “The Next Piece” rated for LV25.
>   LV35: “Reactivate the ECHO Comm System” rated for LV 30 in Crimson Fastness.
>   LV37: Only activated for DLC4 after completing “Loot Larceny” rated for LV38.
>   **LV61**: Only activated for **DLC4** after competing “**You. Will. Die.**”
>
> So the highest DLC1 can be started at is LV35. And the highest DLC4 can be started at is LV61.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. You might be right but I don't have the game installed at the moment and wasn't planning on doing so. If I do, I'll try and remember to check it and then return to this thread :)